# Is it possible to create a live text scanner using a phone camera in ionic/angular?

Tags: angular, cordova, image-processing, camera, scanning

I've been searching for an answer to this for a couple of hours and all I've been able to find is how to take a picture, and scan the picture for text.

What I'm looking for, is how to open your camera, move the camera around, and have the app automatically detect text on the screen without having to take a photo. I've pasted an image of the mockup I was given. If this is possible, any information would be great, thanks!

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvHTc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's possible and it's so easy to do an OCR using ionic you can do it using `tesseract` this youtube video explains how to do it step by step

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6MyNU0jp28